# AJAX request not getting updated values of $_SESSION variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm currently developing a web application and I am using PHP 8.0.3.

For some reason, the Ajax request is not capable of getting the updated value of the SESSION variable unless I forcefully refresh the page. I am calling the ajax function first when the page finishes loading, and then every minute.

I am using AJAX to update the values on a CanvasJS graph.

Can someone help me identify what am I doing wrong?

First, I start the session on a global file that I require on the scripts.

```
session_name("mfm");
session_start();
```

Snippet of my current ajax request on `index.php` page:

```
$.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "php_func/somefile.php",
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        var dbdata = JSON.parse(data);
        var qtyNuts = [];
        var time = [];
        dbdata = dbdata.reverse();
        for (i = 0; i < dbdata.length; i++) {
          time[i] = dbdata[i][1];
          qtyNuts[i] = dbdata[i][0];


        }
...
```

And this is part of the `php_func/some_file.php`:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['bar']))
{
  $processed = $_SESSION['bar'];

  $max = count($processed);
  if($max > 5)
  {
    $max = 5;
  }
  $recent_data = array_slice($processed, -$max);

  foreach($recent_data as $data)
  {
    $kgs = $data[0] / 120.0;

    array_push($kgdata, array($kgs, $data[1]));
  }

  echo json_encode(array_reverse($kgdata));
}
```

I typed `/php_func/some_file.php` on my localhost URL and it works, `kgdata` array is getting updated as the SESSION variable updates.

And this is a snipped of where the session variable is created (this script runs as soon as the page is loaded and then every minute). `Update.php`:

```
$bar = array()
if(isset($_SESSION['bar'])
{
  $bar = $_SESSION['bar'];
}
$b = array(count($buffer), date("H:i:s"));
array_push($bar, $b);
$_SESSION['bar'] = $bar;
```

For some reason, the ajax request does not update the values in the `index.php` graph, unless I forcefully refresh the page. What am I doing wrong?

**I tried**

- Checking session id. They are the same in all files.
- Use `$.post` instead. I have the same issue.
- Change the setInterval for the ajax function to be more than a minute in case there is clashing between `update.php` and `somefile.php`

Comment: _“I am using AJAX to update the values on a CanvasJS graph.”_ - and where exactly are you doing that latter part? All I see you doing so far in your success handler, is write values into some array variables. I kinda doubt that your graph is going to update itself automatically, just because some variables changed …?

Comment: @CBroe I’m doing it. I just didn’t include that part of the code. I’m passing my variables onto my CanvasJS axis variables. But even before that, the variables where I’m saving the data are the ones not being updated, the result from the Ajax is old data.

Comment: _“I am calling the ajax function first when the page finishes loading, and then every minute.”_ - so you are doing the same thing, with both `php_func/somefile.php` and `Update.php`? What’s the point of that to begin with then, why aren’t both steps handled via _one_ request?

Comment: Update.php is from the database which gets around 1200 records a minutes. So I’m creating a buffer with this file that then I process to create the session variables. 
somefile.php is just reading the session variables with the daily data. On a day I can get close to 40 million records, so I needed to create that buffer to be able to get data fast and not re-process data.

Comment: Still don’t see how that would explain why both of those have to happen using two different requests to begin with?

Comment: I can’t. I also got other functions in the Update file that can’t be run by somescript. This two files happen to have the same update time but other SESSION variables are being requested in different time frames with the same result: old data coming back.

Comment: The initial data to show the charts after the first page load or a reload - does that get requested via AJAX as well, or is that part of the HTML the server returned for the page already?

Comment: It’s done through Ajax as well